# kendoTooltip Issue with Angular mobile version

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui, angular13

i'm having an issue with kendotooltip component inside my angular application, it's working for desktop version but not for mobile version(although i added onshow="click" event and still not working).

there is many examples in stackblitz for kendotooltip that are not working when changing to mobile version .

i'm using the tooltip inside a child component that is called from other parent components .in fact if i test with a simple exemple it works, but if i add it inside my child component it does'nt work anymore(even if i add an empty div inside the parent component the tooltip dont work anymore).